# finding the mean and replacing the values in the same dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataset

I have this data set:I want to find the average Viability for any row that wt.Df and founder are the same. I then want to replace those values in the data set

```
 Store;

 founder wt.Df Replicate Block Food_Source Viability
 1       A4  5905         1     1     Regular 0.9523810
 2       A4 24834         1     1     Regular 0.8095238
 3       A4 24834         2     1     Regular 0.8571429
 4       A4 27861         1     1     Regular 0.8095238
 5       A4 27861         2     1     Regular 0.9230769
 12      A3  5905         1     1     Regular 0.9473684
 13      A3 24834         1     1     Regular 0.9047619
 14      A3 27861         1     1     Regular 0.8571429
```

I know this piece of code will find the average between like points, but I dont know how to replace in the data set

```
tmp<- with(Store, mean(Viability[wt.Df == 27861 & founder == "A4"]))
```

Wanted output:

```
founder wt.Df Replicate Block Food_Source Viability
1       A4  5905         1     1     Regular 0.9523810
2       A4 24834         1     1     Regular 0.8333333
4       A4 27861         1     1     Regular 0.8663004
12      A3  5905         1     1     Regular 0.9473684
13      A3 24834         1     1     Regular 0.9047619
14      A3 27861         1     1     Regular 0.8571429
```

Comment: take a look at `?ave`

Comment: scratch that, didn't notice you were condensing the rows on my first read.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of good options that spring to mind. Firstly, plain old `aggregate` from the `base` package:

```
aggregate( Viability ~ wt.Df + founder , FUN = mean , data = store )
#  wt.Df founder Viability
#1  5905      A3 0.9473684
#2 24834      A3 0.9047619
#3 27861      A3 0.8571429
#4  5905      A4 0.9523810
#5 24834      A4 0.8333333
#6 27861      A4 0.8663003
```

Another good option is to use the data.table package and aggregate by grouping variables. I also take the first record of each group for the remaining columns e.g. `Block = Block[1]` as that is what you have in your results...

```
require( data.table )
store <- data.table( store )
store[ , list( Viability = mean(Viability) , Block = Block[1], Replicate = Replicate[1] ) , by = list( wt.Df , founder ) ]
#   wt.Df founder Viability Block Replicate
#1:  5905      A4 0.9523810     1         1
#2: 24834      A4 0.8333333     1         1
#3: 27861      A4 0.8663003     1         1
#4:  5905      A3 0.9473684     1         1
#5: 24834      A3 0.9047619     1         1
#6: 27861      A3 0.8571429     1         1
```

Comment: @ Simon O'Hanlon, I get this: Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
  cannot coerce class "formula" into a data.frame

Answer (score 0):

I would try generating a summary data set and then merging them.

```
library(gdata)
library(plyr)

avg_summary <- ddply(Store, .(wt.DF, founder), summary, viability1 = mean(Viability))
Store <- join(Store, avg_summary)

# delete original Viability column
Store$Viability <- NULL
# rename viability1 -> Viability
Store <- rename.vars(Store, 'viability1', 'Viability')
```

Comment: I think using transform allows the same, but avoids the extra merge (no need to do extra work if not necessary :p)

Comment: @maloneypatr, I tried this solution; however, this is what I get after adding avg_summary <- ddply(Store, .(wt.DF, founder), summary, viability1 = mean(Viability))
Store <- join(Store, avg_summary) Warning message:
In data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
  row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded

Comment: It looks like something is funky in your data frame.  You have 7 columns of data, but only 6 column names.  If you are copying in this data set exactly, remove the row names - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14.  I also noticed a semi-colon.  Are you transferring this from SAS?